# Git shows there is no difference but files are different, and upon merging those files are not merged either?

Tags: git

We have master branch and customBranch. If I go to certain file in both branches they are different.

BUT If make a PR request that file is not shown as different. or if I do `git diff master...customBranch`. That files doesn't show up in diff. And when you merge that file doesn't change.

Comment: Trying pushing to remote. How are you determining if the files are different? Locally only? Have you commited locally and pushed?

Comment: If you are able to do `diff file1 file2` without `git` in front of it, that means you are comparing two local files, and not the same file across 2 branches. After all, if the file is the same, it should have the same name. By the way, you might want to use `..` instead of `...`. Try `git diff master..customBranch -- thatFile`.

Comment: Are the files really different or are for example only line endings different?

Comment: @Robert, `git diff` would show that too.

Comment: i checked the files on github as well, git cloned again, and they were different both places.

Comment: git diff with `..` shows the difference. however, merging doesn't result in those changes being applied, merging happens with changes show with three `...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation you have described here is normal, provided something you *haven't* mentioned is true.  Given that you have not mentioned it, I'll just assume it's true, because otherwise you'd see different behavior from Git.

Let's describe this extra condition.

#### Commits

First, remember that Git is really all about commits.  Branches—or branch *names*, to be precise—are just a way to *find* particular commits.  Git cares about the *commits*, so those are what we need to care about as well.

- Each commit is numbered.  This number is not a simple counting number: instead, it's a big ugly cryptographic hash ID.  It *seems* random but in fact is entirely non-random.  Each commit has a unique hash ID, and every Git everywhere will agree that any given commit, that has whatever hash ID on *your* Git, gets that same hash ID in *their* Git too.
- Each commit has a full snapshot of every file that Git knew about at the time whoever made that commit, made it.  That's the main data inside a commit.
- But each commit also contains the commit number—the hash ID—of the commit that comes *before* that commit.  Or, for a merge commit, it contains two or more hash IDs: the commit that comes before, and the commit(s) merged in.  This commit number (or these numbers) are part of the *metadata*, which also include the name and email address of the commit's author, and anything else useful like that, that's not part of the saved data.

What the above means is that we can *draw* the commits, using backwards-pointing arrows from each commit back to its *parent* (previous) commit.  In a simple linear chain, this looks like:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Using that hash ID, Git can read out the commit itself, including both its saved files, and the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  We say that `H` *points to* `G`.

Of course, with `H` pointing to `G`, we can have Git read out commit `G`.  This gets us the saved snapshot, and the hash ID of earlier commit `F`: `G` points backwards to `F`.  Meanwhile `F` also points backwards.

This chain of backwards-pointing commits *is* the history.  The commits are the history; history is nothing but commits.  But there's one problem here: *how did we find hash ID `H`?*

#### Branch names

Git's answer for finding hash ID `H` is to use a *branch name*.  The name simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

If we make another branch name, we can have both *names* point to commit `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, br1
```

(Note that all these commits are now on both branches at the same time.)

Now that we have more than one name, we need to pick one name to use.  We'll have Git attach the special name `HEAD` to exactly one branch name, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), br1
```

If we now make a new commit, we will get:

```
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br1
```

As you can see, the *name* `master` has moved, to now point to commit `I`.  Commits up through `H` are on both branches, while commit `I` is only on `master`.  Let's make one more commit, and this time, let's make a change to some file *F* that appears in every commit so far, including commits `H` and `I` and our new commit `J`:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br1
```

Note that there is a copy of file *F* in each commit, but it's *different* in `J`, now.

Now let's use `git checkout br1` to go back to old commit `H`, using the name `br1`:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD)
```

Note that no *commits* have changed, but we've gone back to the old version of file *F*.

We'll make some new commits, perhaps to add a new feature, now.  While we do this, **we do not change file *F*.**  We get:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br1 (HEAD)
```

#### Merging does not mean *make same*

If we now ask Git to compare commit `L`, the tip of `br1`, to commit `J`, the tip of `master`, we will see that file *F* is different in these two branches.

Let's use `git checkout master` and run `git merge br1`.  The first step moves our `HEAD` and gets us the versions of each file as they appear in commit `J`, i.e., we get `master`'s version of file *F*.

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br1
```

Now we run `git merge br1`.  Git will:

- Locate the current commit `J` (easy: just find out which name `HEAD` is attached to, and then read that branch name; that's our current commit).
- Locate commit `L` (easy: use the name `br1` to find its hash ID).
- Use the *graph*—the backwards-pointing arrows from commit to commit—to find the *best shared / common commit*.  This part is harder, but it's clear from the drawing that this best shared commit is commit `H`.  That commit is on both branches.  "Earlier" commits like `G` are too, but `H` is better because it's "later".

What Git needs to do now is *combine* our changes.  But we don't have *changes*.  We have *snapshots*.  So Git has to *find* changes, by comparing the snapshot in `H`—that's where the graph diverges—to each of the two branch tip commits.

Comparing the snapshot in `H` vs that in `J` shows that *we* (`master`) changed file *F*.  Comparing the snapshot in `H` vs that in `L` shows that *they* (`br1`) *did not* change file *F*.  So Git will take *our* change, which results in our version of file *F*.

That's really all there is to it: there is no reason to change *F* from how it appears in commit `J`, to how it appears in commit `L`, because the way *F* shows up in `L` matches the way *F* shows up in `H`.  We want the one that's *different*, not the one that is *the same*.

Had we and they both changed file *F*, Git would have to work harder, to combine our two sets of changes.  But here, *we* changed *F* and they didn't, so it was all very easy.

Comment: **tl;dr:** (except in this case d="did" instead of "didn't") Most likely the file in question was modified on master after customBranch branched off from master, and the file was not modified on customBranch since.

Comment: A really comprehensive explanation. Really really useful

Comment: I've read this 3 times and still not sure, but I think it has the answer in it, so I'll try again

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: consider running `git merge-base --all HEAD <otherbranch>` where you would have run `git merge <otherbranch>`. This will very likely print out one raw commit hash ID. (If it prints *more than one*, you have a complicated situation that I deliberately left out to keep the answer simpler.) The one hash ID printed out here is that of the *merge base* commit.

Comment: Take that one hash ID, save it (cut and paste with mouse), and run: `git diff <hash> HEAD`. These are *your changes*, i.e., what you did on your branch. Read these diffs to see what you changed. Separately (maybe in another window), run `git diff <hash> <otherbranch>`. These are *their changes*, i.e., what they did on their branch.

Comment: The merge operation is going to *combine these two sets of changes*. It is not going to make your branch match theirs. It is not going to make their branch match yours. It is only going to *combine* changes, and then apply the combined changes to the *merge base* commit's snapshot.

Comment: Note that when you run `git diff master...customBranch`, with the three dots, Git is going to run `git merge-base --all master customBranch`. That gets the hash ID of the merge base. Then Git runs that *second* diff, `git diff <hash> customBranch`. That's the diff you see in your original question.